# How to overcome error reading source backup vBuckets for bucket when using cbrestorewrapper and cbrestore

Tags: macos, couchbase

sh cbrestorewrapper /users/indacouch/cbbackup http://127.0.0.1:8091 -u development -p pass

throws the following error:

Error reading source backup vBuckets for bucket phr_development

I also tried sh cbrestore /users/indacouch/cbbackup http://127.0.0.1:8091/ --bucket-source=staging --bucket-destination=test -u test -p pass -x rehash=1

and it returned the following error:

s0 error: async operation: error: map missing vbucket_id: 26624; perhaps your source does not have vbuckets; if so, try using moxi (HOST:11211) as a destination on sink: 127.0.0.1:8091 /(staging@172.31.37.75:8091)
error: map missing vbucket_id: 26624; perhaps your source does not have vbuckets; if so, try using moxi (HOST:11211) as a destination

I'm using OS X 10.11.5

Answer (score 2):

including -x rehash=1  should resolve the error. If you run 
cbrestore /users/indacouch/cbbackup http://127.0.0.1:8091/ --bucket-source=staging --bucket-destination=test -u test -p pass -x rehash=1 immediately after another command you can get the same error.
Suggest you add sleep 10 immediately prior cbrestore